# Complex special function implementation in python

Tags: scipy, complex-numbers

I need to run a massive computation involving a large of calls to the special function `scipy.special.exp1` with a complex argument and may migrate the code from python to another language (C). It turns out that only python has an implementation of this function for complex arguments. The C implementation of the GSL only accepts real arguments. How can I get the code from `scipy.special` in order to translate it into C ? Many thanks.

Comment: Note that strictly speaking the question is off-topic because it asks for an off-site resource.

Comment: Regardless, I couldn't resist to look it up: [Pyothon wrapper](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/special/specfun_wrappers.c#L172) and [Fortran implementation](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/special/specfun/specfun.f#L9280). Good luck :)

Comment: Thank you @kazemakase, this is exactly what I was looking for. Concerning you first comment, I couldn't find a SE site that seemed fit better for the question. I'll keep your comment in mind.